# Enable RAML metadata output option not coming

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, raml

I am trying to generate RAML file from my web api core application in Visual studion 2015. I have installed 'RAML Tools for .NET' from the below link.

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/cadcb820-762c-4514-9817-884b7558aaa9/view/Discussions

Still I am not able to get the option "Enable RAML metadata output". Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

RAML metadata for Asp.Net Core is on the roadmap but not available yet:
https://github.com/mulesoft-labs/raml-dotnet-tools/issues/98

Comment: Any work around available by the time roadmap launched?

Comment: You can build the vsix from the develop branch, you'll need to install Visual Studio extensibility extension